# Websites download unusual file in certain browsers

Tags: macos, internet, browser

Working from OSX El Capitan 10.11.1, can't currently test this on a different OS. (Update: a friend checked on OSX 10.10.5 and everything seems fine there)

Recently, some websites became inaccessible via Chrome or Firefox, but they seem to load normally in Safari ([Code School](https://www.codeschool.com) and [Backbone Tutorials](https://backbonetutorials.com) are the ones I recall offhand). If I try to open them in Chrome or FF, a weird file is downloaded instead. The name of the file typically reflects the page I was trying to reach, and no matter which site or page I try to access, the file contents are always the same.

Opera and Vivaldi behave the same way. Also, [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com) also downloads a file, but instead of seeming based off of the page name it is always called "d20.html", also the actual website loads correctly for Tumblr in addition to the file being downloaded.

I got IPs for Codeschool and Backbone Tutorials from [get-site-ip](http://get-site-ip.com/) and tried to access those urls directly from my browser, but was met with a Cloudfare error page (Err 1003, direct ip access not allowed) in both cases. I went to Cloudfare's website to see what it was, and the homepage loaded fine the first time, but every other page (as well as the homepage on subsequent visits) has the same issues as the other sites I've mentioned. Also, it seems portions of Codeschool that are on a subdomain (e.g., http://gitreal.codeschool.com/) are accessible.

Here's the hexdump of the file:

```
0000000 00 00 12 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 80 00
0000010 04 7f ff ff ff 00 05 00 ff ff ff 00 00 04 08 00
0000020 00 00 00 00 7f ff 00 00 00 00 08 07 00 00 00 00
0000030 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 0a
000003a
```

Omitting nulls, here's what that comes to: [Device Control 2], [End of Transmission], [End of Text], [Padding], [End of Transmission], [Delete], ÿ, ÿ, ÿ, [Enquiry], ÿ, ÿ, ÿ, [End of Transmission], [Backspace], [Delete], ÿ, [Backspace], [Bell], [Start of Heading]

Additionally, in vim I noticed that this file was automatically converted from `latin-1` to `utf-8`.

Firefox detects that these are DMS files, Chrome doesn't seem to know what they are.

Since I can get to these sites via Safari, this isn't a major issue, but I am still curious about what is happening. I initially assumed it was a serverside issue at Codeschool, but after finding another site with the same issue and also discovering that the sites work in Safari, I'm not as convinced of that.

What could be causing this issue and is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all browser extensions and plug-ins in the affected browsers? Have you looked at what HTTP headers they're sending and receiving? Have you looked at what IP addresses they're connecting to?

Comment: @Spiff Opera/Vivaldi were fresh installs; not sure how to effectively check headers/IPs offhand

Answer (score 0):

This is an HTTP2 frame (and this is one of the top Google results when you search for that hex string).

The downloaded file is likely caused by a misconfiguration where HTTP2 is sent to a client expecting HTTP.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-4.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).